# Rhel + Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations - when installing network driver

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kernel-module, rhel

we try to installe the network driver - `i40e` on rhel server 7.2 version , ( kernel - 3.10.0-512 )

as the following

```
# tar zxf i40e-2.12.6.tar.gz
# cd i40e-2.12.6/src
# make install
common.mk:82: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations.
common.mk:83: *** Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g.
common.mk:84: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again.  Stop.
```

on other server ( rhel 7.2 ) its installed successfully as the following ( this is the second `make install` , so the output is little different from the first time )

```
# cd src/
# make install
*** The target kernel has CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL enabled, but
*** the signing key cannot be found. Module signing has been
*** disabled for this build.
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'
Installing modules...
*** The target kernel has CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL enabled, but
*** the signing key cannot be found. Module signing has been
*** disabled for this build.
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'
  INSTALL /tmp/i40e-2.12.6/src/i40e.ko
  DEPMOD  3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64'
/sbin/depmod -e -F /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/source/System.map  -a 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Updating initramfs...
make mandocs_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/i40e-2.12.6/src'
Copying manpages...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/i40e-2.12.6/src'
```

what is the reason ? that we get the following errors:

```
common.mk:82: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations.
common.mk:83: *** Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g.
common.mk:84: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again.  Stop.
```

reference - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24411/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-40-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in the error message: "Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g. kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again.".

Comment: so if we have kernel -  kernel - 3.10.0-512  , then how to know the right driver version?

Comment: **Driver** version is not directly correlated with the **kernel** version. If some driver can be installed only on a subset of kernel versions, this should be noted by the manufacture of the driver. Otherwise one should only guess about valid kernel versions. BTW, how a versioning relates to your question post?

Comment: so I am little confuse , sinse driver 140e is failed on kernel  3.10.0-512  , then I am understand fro your words that we need to search the right driver for this kernel version , for sure 140e is for for 3.10.0-327.el7 , the question is how to find the right driver ?

Comment: No, you understand my words wrong. You need to install `kernel-devel` or similar package which provides build tree for your running kernel. Only after that you will be able to build modules for that kernel.

Comment: ok so if for example the kernel is 3.10.0-512 then kernel-devel should maybe have this kernel version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223258/discussion-between-jessica-and-tsyvarev).